# How to find the default file manager?

Tags: linux, bash, gnome, kde

as a Linux user, I see that some applications can request a path to be opened and this causes a file manager to be launched. I'd like to do this programmatically, but how can I know which is the default file manager? Is there a way to find this info? Any environment variable?
By "file manager", I mean applications that allow you to administer your files: create, rename, create folders, etc., like Nautilus (in GNOME) or Dolphin (in KDE).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "Default File Manager for Linux". It all depends how you might be trying to open one. If you ask XDG, then you'll have to check what XDG thinks this file manager should be. Same deal for any other "environment", such as Gnome, or KDE. If you have all of them installed, it's perfectly possible (and fine) for each of them to have a different "default file manager".

The case for default apps seems to come mainly from Windows. Over there, we only have one environment, the one Windows presents us with. As such, the notion of a default application is indeed effectively system wide. This is not the case with Linux.

What you might perceive as default apps under Linux, such as what is stored in the $EDITOR environment variable, is not as much a "true" default app, as simply a convention used by a lot of people who write system tools and scripts. Feel free to define $FILEMANAGER, if that suits your use case.

Comment: I was thinking there might be an environment variable for this, and actually thought about defining one. Nice answer, thank you very much.

Comment: I think you mean XFCE instead of XDG?

Comment: I mean XDG: http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html

Answer (score 32):

Use the `xdg-mime` command to this. xdg should be desktop-environment agnostic (eg `xdg-open` will pass the arguments on to the correct file opener). To get the default file manager use:

```
xdg-mime query default inode/directory
```

---

[Source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xdg-open)

Comment: This should be the correct answer.

Comment: @crypdick It's not _the_ correct answer, it's _a_ correct answer for applications that use XDG. I suggest reading [the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Default_applications) for more info.

Answer (score 19):

You can use `xdg-open <DIR>` to launch the file manager on a directory.  You might be able to query some `xdg` application to find out what file manager is used.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will try to use this to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

i just came accross the same problem. (i would rather like to comment but my reputation isnt high enough)

i tried `xdg-open` and it startet EasyTag which is a id3-tag-editor (somehow funny) :-)

i tried Gerhard Burgers answer

```
xdg-mime query default inode/directory
```

and that returned `dolphin.desktop` in my case.

so in my case the correct solution was (replacing ".dektop" with ""):

```
xdg-mime query default inode/directory | sed 's/.desktop//g'
```

but i only testet this on this system i am running

Comment: Some .desktop files exec something else than the filename. Something like this might work: `grep -i exec /usr/share/applications/$(xdg-mime query default inode/directory) | head -1 | cut -d= -f2- | cut -d% -f1`.

Answer (score 2):

Seems everybody mentioned the `inode/directory` MIME-type and the `xdg-open` should works in most of the cases for your need (programmatically open a directory via a file manager), but sometimes wrong application (which is not a file manager, e.g. Visual Studio Code) can also associate it with the `inode/directory` as the default application.

In addition there is also a [file-manager-interface for D-Bus](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/file-manager-interface/) (`org.freedesktop.FileManager1` in Session Bus) which can be used for your requirement so you can also use this if your file manager support this D-Bus interface. Please make sure if you can use it since not all file manager implemented this, currently it seems *Dolphin* (KDE), *Nautilus* (GNOME) and *Deepin File Manager* (DDE) implemented this D-Bus interface. And to find out which process owner this D-Bus interface (you don't need to do it if you just would like to request a path to be opened via a file manager programmatically), see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379810/find-out-the-owner-of-a-dbus-service-name)

Comment: This is what I came looking for. After applying all the tricks with `xdg-mime` and `mimeo`, turns, out something else was at work and this was dbus filemanager. A quick look with `d-feet` reveals that the thunar file manager is registered in xfce using dbus. Now on to finding a way to replace that